# Use update query to update Table with form values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

When a User logs in using my `Login` form I want my `Update` query to pick it up and store that `User_Name` into `Login_Status.Last_User`, a one record table.

The field is referred to as [Forms]![Login]![User_Name] so I try to do this:

```
UPDATE Login_Status 
   SET LAST_USER = [Forms]![Login]![User_Name];
```

However, this does not work. The query runs without error and doesn't update the field. Does Access not take Form References as a valid values to update tables?

UPDATE: If the query is ran by its self it will update the table. However, if it is ran by the macro it won't.

UPDATE:
[image]
Notes: Delete query clears the Login_Status table of data.
       `Gaurd_Dog` checks the `User_Name` and `Password` field against the database and inserts the results into the `Login_Status.Status` field.

UPDATE: I just shut down and restarted the database and it worked. This is a similar solution to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165745/insert-into-based-on-the-results-of-an-iif-statment). Must be an Access problem.

Comment: If it's a one-record table, why are you using a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth well...

Comment: How are you executing that query? You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7296893) to see which kinds of parameters support which kind of execution

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think I just answered your question in the update.

Comment: If the macro is the problem, share the macro